# Importing products with custom options

Tags: magento2, import, custom-options, magento-2.1.3

I'm trying to add custom options for my products, using import product tools.

This is how my csv file looks like:

```
sku,custom_options
1001BG,"name=Line 1,type=field,required=0,price=0.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,max_characters=5"
```

This is the error I get:

> "General system exception happened"

Any hint is appreciated.

P.S.: I tried to Convert to `UTF-8-BOM`, still not working.

I use `Magento CE 2.1.3`.

Comment: Is there any error from log?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Custom options are processed in

```
\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Option::_parseCustomOptions()
```

There is line

```
1859 $options[$name][$k]['_custom_option_store'] = $rowData[Product::COL_STORE_VIEW_CODE];
```

Expectations here are that your CSV file contains column `store_view_code`. In case the column is absent, `E_NOTICE` is triggered.

For every error Magento generates an exception. So here low level exception with next text is throwed:

```
Notice: Undefined index: store_view_code in /var/www/html/magetwo.vg/app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product/Option.php on line 1859
```

To solve this just add empty column `store_view_code` to CSV file

```
sku,store_view_code,custom_options
1001BG,,"name=Line 1,type=field,required=0,price=0.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,max_characters=5"
```