# magento 2.1.5 - General system exception happened - import products

Tags: error, import, products, magento2.1.5

Im start learning `Magento 2`, made a fresh  install of `Magento 2.1.5` by command line on a VM with

- Ubuntu server 14.04
- PHP 7.0.16
- MySQL 5.7.17
- Apache 2.4

Tried to import several times the products
1 - added a product manually and exported the csv, then deleted the product and tried to import.
2 - downloaded the sample file and tried to import it

Always have the same error:

> General system exception happened

Have seen the logs and don't see anything unsual..

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

UPDATE: Problems during the installation of mysql server, reinstalled everthing resolved!

Answer (score 1):

We faced this issue when we were trying to import custom options.

As shared in [Importing products with custom options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158060/importing-products-with-custom-options)

To solve this just add empty column store_view_code to CSV file.

The sequence of this column is also important, its usually the second column.

Answer (score 0):

We can able to overcome the issue by creating a new source (Stores -> Inventory -> Sources) with code 'default'.

While debugging, It tries to insert the data into inventory_source_item table with source_code = 'default'. And since that source_code is a foreign key to the inventory_source table, it showed the error. When creating the source with code 'default', it then fixed the issue.